# Bookmarking an embedded pdf on iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf, web

I have a web page with an embedded pdf file. I can bookmark pages in the pdf using the query string and passing those values to the source tag. 
While this works well on a desktop browser, I can't seem to get bookmarks to work in an iPad. Two finger scrolling works, but not the bookmarks.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the mac forums as well

Comment: I've been through the Mac forums. I'm not finding too many people asking this question anywhere. The issue is associated with the iPad. None of the browsers that I've tried on iPad (Safari, Opera, Dolphin) will read the bookmarks in the query as outlined by Adobe. I was hoping for maybe some javascript workaround ideas.

Comment: My workaround for those who might be curious:
The website is php/mysql. The embedded pdfs and their bookmarks are listed in a database table. I'm using a sniffer to determine whether or not the user is on an ipad or desktop.
The desktop bookmarks are linked using Adobe's protocol, i.e., http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3. If the user is on an ipad, bookmarking extracts a pdf page using Imagemagick and links to that page.
It's inelegant and creates more files - I wanted to stay away from that. But it works.